# How to insert Plain Text Context or Rich Text Context in Word Doc using Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I would like to insert Plain text context or Rich Text context to a Word Document using java. I would like to read word Document word by Word and add context to a particular word. I had searched it out everywhere and not able to find an implementation for it. Can someone please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

Apache POI is the go-to reference regarding interaction with Office documents, even with [examples on how to extract data](https://poi.apache.org/text-extraction.html) and [how to interact with Word documents](https://poi.apache.org/components/document/).